# Trigonometric Identities of $\cot$

Tags: trigonometry

Originally this was a physics question, but I am trying to solve this (if possible at the current state).

$\theta_{2}=\cot^{-1}(\cot(\theta_{2}))=\cot^{-1}(-\frac{VM}{mv'}\sec(\theta_{1})+\cot(\theta_{1}))$

where $M$, $V$, $v'$, and $m$ are scalars and $M$ and $m$ greater than $0$.

Comment: I assume you're solving for $\theta_1$?

Comment: Leads to a fourth degree equation in $ \sin $ or $\cos \theta$